# List of mail servers using DKIM, SPF and SenderID

Tags: postfix, authentication, email

I am setting up Postfix mail server. What I want to know is that, what the popular mail server's like yahoo, gmail, AOL, Microsoft Outlook server etc. use for sender identification of e-mails.

e.g: Which one use SPF or DKIM or SenderId etc.

Any listing enumerating about these properties would be highly useful.

Thanks in advance

Ashish

Comment: FYI, Outlook is a client, not a server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yahoo! uses DKIM. 
Google uses both SPF and DKIM.
Microsoft/Hotmail use SenderID, which is a slight variation of SPF.

Outblaze (Now IBM iNotes) uses neither.

What is your actual goal though?

Comment: My actual goal is to create a setup of a postfix installation that uses best of all available mail server's in terms of standards.

Comment: You're not limited to using only one. I've correct SPF records and dkim-milter running on my postfix server.

Comment: There is no "best". Why are you doing this in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Yahoo! is using Domainkeys which is different than DKIM.

Answer (score 1):

Google is using SPF. Some headers from email:

```
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of EMAILADDRESS designates IPNUMBER as permitted sender) client-ip=IPNUMBER;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of EMAILADDRESS t designates IPNUMBER as permitted sender) smtp.mail=EMAILADDRESS
```